# I want to implement foreign key in my Springboot project but I get the following errors

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.Tue Oct 10 17:11:14 IST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.
>   hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement.

STS Error:

```
Before changing the code

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolation
Exception
: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  
(workdemo.officeinfo, CONSTRAINT idFOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES mytable 
(id))

After implementing joincolumn

 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
 creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
 resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/
 HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
 nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier 
 specified for entity:com.infidata.modal.MyTable
```

POJO( value with getters and setters,also 
     generated value)

```
Office.java
package com.infidata.modal;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="officeinfo")
public class Office {
@Id
private int sno;
private String batchno;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id" )
private MyTable myTable;
private String fees;
private String reciptno;
private String trainer;

public Office() {

}

public int getSno() {
    return sno;
}
public void setSno(int sno) {
    this.sno = sno;
}
public String getBatchno() {
    return batchno;
}
public void setBatchno(String batchno) {
    this.batchno = batchno;
}

public String getFees() {
    return fees;
}
public void setFees(String fees) {
    this.fees = fees;
}
public String getReciptno() {
    return reciptno;
}
public void setReciptno(String reciptno) {
    this.reciptno = reciptno;
}
public String getTrainer() {
    return trainer;
}
public void setTrainer(String trainer) {
    this.trainer = trainer;
}
public Office(String batchno,String fees, String reciptno,String trainer) {
    super();
    this.batchno = batchno;
    this.fees = fees;
    this.reciptno = reciptno;
    this.trainer=trainer;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Office [sno=" + sno + ", batchno=" + batchno + ",fees=" + fees
            + ", reciptno=" + reciptno + ",trainer=" + trainer + "]";
}
}
```

MyTable.java

```
package com.infidata.modal;
@Entity
public class MyTable {

 }
```

Database(name of database is workdemo)

User table(Table name: mytable)

```
  CREATE TABLE `mytable`

  ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `college` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `branch` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `semester` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(105) NOT NULL,
  `internship` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `batch` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `startdate` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `enddate` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   )
   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
   COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Office table(Table name:office)

```
   CREATE TABLE `office`
  (`sno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `batchno` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fees` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `reciptno` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`),
  KEY `id_idx` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `mytable` (`id`)
)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The id(foreign key) in office table should be autoincremented with reference to student id column attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you defined the entity class :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

When you use JPA, you must specify the target entity of the relationship, not the field from database.
    Your definition just tells the hibernate to generate an int value which will not correspond to a real entity.
It should be something like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id" )
private User user;
```

Your office object will be

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "officeinfo")
public class Office {

    @Id
    private int sno;
    private String batchno;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;

    private String fees;
    private String reciptno;
    private String trainer;
   // getters and setters;
 }
```

Please make sure that @Id is only on sno and you don't have on another fields, otherwise it will fail with composite key exception. Please remove id from your object, it is the foreign key to User and it is handled by:

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id")
 private User user;
```

Comment: I did implement your code but it's giving me this error :
 `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
 with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.infidata.modal.Office.myTable references an unknown entity: com.infidata.modal.MyTable.`

Comment: did you make a class for MyTable annotated with @Entity? similar with Office class

Comment: I did now its giving this  `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.infidata.modal.MyTable.`

Comment: you don't have @Id on your id field in MyTable

Comment: my POJO is in Ofice.java                           
        `@Entity @Table(name="officeinfo")
        public class Office {

 @Id
 private int sno;
 private String batchno;
 
 @ManyToOne
 @Id
        @JoinColumn(name = "id" )
         private MyTable myTable;   // i created this extra class for the new code 
        implementation
        private String fees;
 private String reciptno;
 private String trainer;
     }`

Comment: please update your original question and post also MyTable, it is hard to follow

Comment: good, @Entity
public class MyTable {

 } is missing the id, in your table defintion is Integer id. So add in this class @ Id private Integer id;

Comment: I implemented the id in my table its giving this error . `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable: com.infidata.modal.Office`

Comment: do you have a github repository with this project?

Comment: Yes, the table MyTable is actually User entity, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey,i tried the new implementation but its giving this error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null.`

Comment: Hello @ShashankNaik, I took a loot at your branch and you have some things confused over there. The annotation id should be only on your primary key field, otherwise it will try to resolve it as composite key -> it will fail, it needs special handling. You don't need to declare your foreign key field, you should must declare it in @ JoinColumn (name = "--HERE IT IS YOUR FOREIGN KEY--") and hibernate will do the magic.

Comment: Hi, I tried it it's not Autofilling the id attribute(for office) in both frontend and backend what should I do?